# Python OOP making new classes vs function parameters

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have an abstract base class for data processing. The concrete class of spectral processing inherits the ABC data processing. But now within spectral processing, I can do things in different ways. Like calculate different types of transforms or different types of filters. I have 2 ideas

1. Make a filter function within concrete spectral processing class and pass it a string consisting of which type of filter to implement.
2. Make a separate filter class that uses spectral processing class as a base class and implement different filtering functions in this class.

Which one of the two ideas is better

Comment: This could benefit from illustrating the two approaches using actual code.

Comment: Depends on the later classes you are going to build. If you want to build them on top of the base class or the filter class. I would say if the filter functions don't need to be in the class, define them as independent functions. Functional programming is much better than having classes with many inheritance and functions.

Comment: There are a lot more options you aren’t even mentioning here. For example, even if the filter has some meaningful state, is there a reason for the filter class to be a subclass, instead of an independent class that has a spectral processor as an attribute? Or, if it’s just “parasitic” on the state of the spectral processor, but you have other reasons to have a hierarchy, maybe you want a suite of composable mixins rather than a fixed hierarchy. And so on. Which one is appropriate depends on a whole lot of factors that you haven’t told us, so we can’t tell you which to use.